# Equality of Riemann and Lebesgue integrals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

In Real Analysis by Royden (4th) edition, Royden has the following proof that Riemann integrability implies Lebesgue integrability for a bounded function $f$ defined on a closed, bounded interval $[a,b]$.

I am not understanding the logic here. He claims that because each step function is a simple function the first equality implies the second. However, even though every step function is a simple function, it is not true the other way around. That is, there are simple functions that are not step functions, and the second inequality is therefore taking the $\sup$ over this larger class of functions. So, theoretically, couldn't the second equality yield a different result than the first?

[image: Proof of Theorem 3 on page 74]

Comment: What are those $(R)$'s doing in there?

Comment: The (R) means Riemann integral, as opposed to without the (R) which means Lebesgue integral @zhw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $\sup_1 \le \sup_2 \le \inf_2 \le \inf_1.$ Since $\sup_1 =\inf_1,$  these numbers are all the same.  (Here the subscript $1$ refers to your first line, and the subscript $2$ refers to you second line.)

Comment: Makes sense. Thank you!